# Extendable/Customizable/Modular Lightweight Markup for PHP

Tags: php, markdown, markup, textile

Im planning a web application written in PHP (with Symfony) where I'd like to use a lightweight markup language. There will be two use cases in the app with different requirements:

1. Short texts (`<input type="text">`) where the user will need be able to insert icons/symbols into the text and markup inline elements (`<strong>`, but also `<small>`), but no "block level" features such as headlines or lists, nor any links.
2. Longer texts (`<textarea>`) where the user mostly needs headlines, bullet point lists and again "span" elements, but also no links.

The problem I have, is that all markup libraries I've looked at (mainly Textile and Markdown, but I searched and looked at some other alternatives) have too many features, that can't be (de)activated during runtime, and are not easily extendable without modifying their actual code, which I'd prefer to avoid, or I'd have to parse and modify the generated HTML, which isn't nice either.

So my question is: Is there a more extendable/customizable/modular lightweight markup library for PHP considering following features?

1. Easily deactivate certain features, not only permanently because the user shouldn't be able to use them at all (e.g. Links or inline HTML), but preferringly also during runtime, because of the two use cases with different requirements.
2. Easily modify the generated HTML to use different elements. For example, have `# Headline` generate a `h3` instead of `h1` because `h1` and `h2` are reserved.
3. Easily add features such as:

   - Simple placeholders for a fixed set of small icons/symbols (this is the one thing I know Markdown has basic support for).
   - Custom inline elements, for example have `~Test~` convert to `<small>Text</small>`.

Comment: *(reference)* [Lightweight Markup Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language)

Comment: @Gordan Thanks, I had already checked that and, unless I missed something, none of those come even close to my requirements.

Comment: out of curiosity: what keyboards do you guys have that you constantly misspell my name with an a. A and O are on the opposite side on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try Texy, http://texy.info/en/

It is very good configurable and extendable.